# MEAN : why some views are rendered by expressJS and others by angularJS

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, mean.io

I don't understand why some views are rendered by expressJS (like the signup.jade view) and others by angularJS (like articles/edit.html)

I don't neither understand how the signup view for example is rendered in angularjs as the /signup route is not registered in the angularjs config.js…

Can i have some enlightments please ?

Comment: express is on the SERVER side, and angular on the CLIENT side

Comment: why the signup page is not a angular page connected to a service ?

Comment: You can find a short answer here: http://meanjs.org/docs.html#backend-views
Even if it is not the same stack I think both have similar logic.